# Seeking Strava users routes on city scale?

Tags: data, france, strava

I'm a GIS student and I would like to access all the routes used by the users of Strava at the scale of a city (Rennes, France) in SHP, GEOJSON or JSON format.

Is it possible to make requests by city or geographic coordinates on the Strava API?

Is there an application "for dummies" where you could download all the data inside a polygon?

I use QGIS if it's relevant and I have almost no knowledge of using APIs in general. I don't even know if the data is free, I try to contact Strava METRO but they didn't answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data is not available for free.

The product is Strava Metro as you said (https://metro.strava.com/), and they sell the data.

You cannot access other peoples tracks through the API without their permission.

Answer (score 2):

You could get summarised information from Heatmaps https://www.strava.com/heatmap#12.18/172.60535/-43.55162/hot/ride

Or for individual efforts flybys 
 https://labs.strava.com/flyby/viewer/#1556816875?c=rb68pdy3&z=C&t=1QyE0H&a=6yPLXAs0y1xpYctcyeTJXFDzylzmYctcX5J-XQ   This shows other strava users who passed near you on an activity, or duplicated your path by a decent percentage at the same time.

Downside of using either info is that you're probably breaching terms and conditions.  If you need the data, look at commercial access to the API, or ask a group of your riding friends to share their rides with you directly, making it not strava's data.